# I have 12 months of datasets on my desktop and I want to concat them in one dataset in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

How can I concat them by using loops?

```
files = [file for file in os.listdir('./Pandas-Data-Science-Tasks-master/SalesAnalysis/sales_Data')]
concat_data = pd.DataFrame()

for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv('./Pandas-Data-Science-Tasks-master/SalesAnalysis/sales_Data'+file)
    concat_data = pd.concat(concat_data,df)
concat_data
```

I tried doing this by watching a yt video but it is not working for me.

Comment: Why does the code you've listed not work?

Comment: Maybe you want to actually write the result to disk instead of just concatenating in memory?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) `pd.concat`'s first argument is *a sequence or mapping of Series or DataFrame objects*.

So your code should looks like:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

data_dir = Path('./Pandas-Data-Science-Tasks-master/SalesAnalysis/sales_Data')
data_frames = [pd.read_csv(data_dir / file) for file in os.listdir(data_dir)]

concat_data = pd.concat(data_frames)
print(concat_data.to_string())
```

If it does not works please check if all csv files have same structure.